# Long lists in React Native: pagination or infinite list?

Tags: list, react-native, react-native-flatlist, catalog

I have online store catalog. Let it be 1000 items.
How long lists usually done in mobile apps: infinite scroll or pagination? What are best practices?

My thoughts:
If to have a think, I can't remember I've ever seen pagination in mobile apps. Infinite scroll is almost everywhere. It is good, but if you want to find necessary goods you can't just press number of page you already know, you should scroll this big list. But you can search it, nd system of likes can be a great help - you can just save what you want so that you don't need to scroll lists again and again. 
Infinite lists is a standart?

Performance of FlatList enough to render 1000 of elements or there is some other component for that purpose?

Comment: Infinite scrolling is the preferred mobile UI pattern. FlatList should handle 1000 elements if but YMMV

Comment: Thanks you. I understand that the question is simple, but you could post your comment as answer so that I could accept it. ) And here is continuation, could you please look at it?